# IOS: open and close some view controllers

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

In my app I have the following configuration to open my view controllers:

When I write **"pushViewController"** I use a navigation controller, and when I write **"present"** I use a `presentModalViewController`.

```
firtsView -> (pushviewcontroller) -> secondOneView -> (present) -> thirdOneView -> (present) -> fourthView

firstView -> (pushviewcontroller) -> secondTwoView -> (present) -> thirdTwoView
```

This is the scheme of my app to organize my view controllers. Then my question is:

What's the way to return from **"fourthView"** (that is when I go back from **"fourthView"**) to **"secondTwoView"**?

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 5):

Yes there are.

The `UIViewController` offers different methods to dismiss a view controller depending on if you presented it modally or not. These are :

```
-(void)dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated; // modal
-(void)dismissViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)flag
                          completion:(void (^)(void))completion;
```

You will need to dismiss them one by one.
Also, take time to read the [View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457) from Apple.

Using a `UINavigationController` you may pop to any view controller using :

```
-(NSArray *)popToViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                       animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

Alternatively, another method let you pop just one :

```
-(UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use presentViewController

i think you have to dismiss viewController one by one

but if you navigationcontroller only, then you can pop to viewController you want

Answer (score 0):

1. in thirdOneView's viewcontroller, do dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO
2. in secondOneView's viewcontroller do dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO again.
3. in secondOneView's viewcontroller do popViewControllerAnimated:NO
4. in firstView's Viewcontroller do pushViewController to secondTwoView

If you want some animation. I would suggest to do it manually by using CoreAnimation. Since

```
-(void)dismissViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)flag
                      completion:(void (^)(void))completion;
```

is only available after iOS5.